# Departments need update information using Workflow

Tags: sharepoint

We have some data on the 3rd party tool called Canary. When users add or edit items on that tool, the department needs to know the information from canary through Workflow using email. If Anyone has idea ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a workflow on the base list? When an item is edited run the workflow to email who needs to be emailed?